# Tell jest to handle Vite's "?raw" syntax

Tags: jestjs, vite

Vite allows to import files as raw strings using

```
import foo from "foo.txt?raw"
```

However, jest complains that it cannot find the file. I found the jest-raw-loader, but I don't know how to tell it to apply raw loading to the "?raw" syntax.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, jest-raw-loader was made for webpack... Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to `moduleNameMapper` it worked.

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  ".*\\.txt\\?raw": "jest-raw-loader"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid pulling in a dependency on `jest-raw-loader`, you could keep your own transform local to the project:

```
// jest.config.cjs

moduleNameMapper: {
  '\\?raw$': '<rootDir>/test-setup/__mocks__/raw.cjs', 
},
transform: {
  '\\?raw$': '<rootDir>/test-setup/rawTransform.cjs',
}
```

*( Update those paths to whatever yours are)*

And the custom transform, that simply returns a string in place of your `?raw` file:

```
// test-setup/rawTransform.cjs

module.exports = {
  process() {
    return { code: `module.exports = '';` };
  },
  getCacheKey() {
    // The output is always the same, so use a literal cache key.
    return 'rawTransform';
  },
};
```